# Is there any ubuntu package can replace to libnagios-plugin-perl for Ubuntu18?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, nagios, system-monitoring

I am working on ubuntu18.04 and I need to install libnagios-plugin-perl. But it seems that this package is not available for ubuntu18 up.

```
apt install libnagios-plugin-perl
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From googling, my guess is that this package was renamed `libmonitoring-plugin-perl` in bionic (18.04).